# Did I understand the following quicksort algorithm correctly?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to understand the given algorithm and here are my thoughts:

`A` is the given array... `x` stands for the number which is on the left side of the pivot element, `y` stands for the number which is on the right side of the pivot element. (Let's say the pivot element is the element on the very right side of the array.) And A[y] stands for the pivot element?

If I understood correctly, the algorithm first searches from `x` towards `y` until first number is greater or equal `A[y]`, then search from `y` towards `x` until first number is smaller or equal `A[y]`.
After, swap both numbers and repeat if `i` hasn't reached `j`. In the end the numbers left from `i` are smaller than `A[y]` and the numbers right from `j` are larger than `A[y]`... Also move `A[y]` to the middle.
What do you think about this? Am I right? 
Maybe you could give an example with a random array? I cannot do this yet I believe.

```
Algorithm Quicksort
1   func int div (A array; x, y integer) {
2   num = A[y];
3   i = x;
4   j = y-1;
5   repeat
6       while (A[i] <= num and i < y)
7           i = i+1;
8       end while;
9       while (A[j] >= num and j > x)
10          j = j-1;
11      end while;
12      if i < j then
13          swap (A[i], A[j]);
14      end if;
15  until i >= j;
16  swap (A[i], A[y]);
17  return i;
18  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the algorithm it looks like x and y mark the left and right bounds of the sorting algorithm within an array (to sort the complete array, you'd use x = 0 and y = A.length). The pivot element is the rightmost one (at index y).

Then, i starts at x (the left bound) and compares each element with the pivot A[y]. It increases up to an index, at which the element is larger than A[y].
j starts at y (the right bound) and does the complementary: it decreases until it reaches an index, at which an element smaller than A[y] is found.

If i is still smaller than j, these two elements (at index i and j) are then swapped, meaning all elements from x to i are smaller than A[y], all elements from j to y are larger than A[y]. In this case, there are still elements between the indices i and j, that have not been 'seen' by the algorithm.
This procedure is repeated until eventually, the complete array is partitioned into the lower 'half' (all smaller than A[y]) and the upper 'half' (all larger than A[y]). One element larger than A[y] is then swapped with A[y] and the index between the two partitions is then returned.

In conclusion, your algorithm only partitions the array into elements smaller than A[y] and elements larger than A[y]. Repeating this recursively on both partitions will eventually sort them completely.

Example:

```
A = [ 4 7 9 2 5 1 3 8 6 ]
--> called with x = 0, y = 8 (thus, partitioning the complete array)
e.g. div([ 4 7 9 2 5 1 3 8 6 ], 0, 8)

 xi             j   y
[ 4 7 9 2 5 1 3 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=0, j=7

  x i           j   y
[ 4 7 9 2 5 1 3 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=1, j=7
A[i]=7 >= A[y]=6 -> first while loop ends

  x i         j     y
[ 4 7 9 2 5 1 3 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=1, j=6
A[j]=3 <= A[y]=6 -> second while loop ends

  x i         j     y
[ 4 3 9 2 5 1 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=1, j=6
swapped A[i] and A[j] (i and j stay the same!) -> repeat until i<j

  x   i       j     y
[ 4 3 9 2 5 1 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=2, j=6

  x   i     j       y
[ 4 3 9 2 5 1 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=2, j=5

  x   i     j       y
[ 4 3 1 2 5 9 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=2, j=5
swapped -> repeat (i<j)

  x     i   j       y
[ 4 3 1 2 5 9 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=3, j=5

  x       i j       y
[ 4 3 1 2 5 9 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=4, j=5

  x        ij       y
[ 4 3 1 2 5 9 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=5, j=5
first while ends again

  x       j i       y
[ 4 3 1 2 5 9 7 8 | 6 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=5, j=4
second while ends again

j>i -> don't swap

j>i -> don't repeat

swap A[i] and A[y]
  x       j i       y
[ 4 3 1 2 5 6 7 8 | 9 ] x=0, y=8, A[y]=6, i=5, j=4

return i=5

Now, all elements between x and i are smaller than your ORIGINAL A[y] (which is now different!) and all elements between i+1 and y are smaller than the ORIGINAL A[y].
Next, you'd call div([ 4 3 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 ], 0, 5) and div([ 4 3 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 ], 6, 8) or more abstract: div(A, x, i) and div(A, i+1, y).
```

Comment: Big thanks to you, now I can really say I understood it :-)

Comment: added an example for your understanding... not the best one, but at least I tried